# Jasmine test to call function when value is null

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function that returns me to a previous page. This works fine, and I want to test it in jasmine, but I cant't get the clickReturnToPage test to pass when the value is null.

```
var ReturntoPage = {

    returnTo: function(fromPageObject){
        $('.btnholder').append('<input class="returnTo" type="button" value="Return to Page" />');
        ReturntoPage.clickReturntoPage();
    },

    disableReturnButton: function (disableFlag) {
        (disableFlag == true) ? $('.returnTo').addClass('disabledButton') : $('.returnTo').removeClass('disabledButton');
        $('.returnTo').prop('disabled', disableFlag);
    },

    clickReturnToPage: function(){
        var lastSearch = sessionStorage.getItem('prev');
        if(lastSearch != null){
            ReturntoPage.disableReturnButton(false);
        }else{
            ReturntoPage.disableReturnButton(true);
        }

        $(".returnTo").bind("click", function() {
            ReturntoPage.redirect();
        });
    },

    redirect:function(){
         lastSearch = sessionStorage.getItem('lastSearch');
         // got to that page
    },
};
```

Here is the tests I am running.

```
describe("Return to page", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        setFixtures('<input class="returnTo" type="button" value="Return to Page" />');
    });

    it("should send false to disableReturnButton when last search is not null", function () {
        lastSearch = "aa";  
        spyOn(ReturntoPage, 'disableReturnButton');

        ReturntoPage.clickReturnToPage();
       // console.log("lastSearch = " + lastSearch);
        expect(ReturntoPage.disableReturnButton).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
    });

    it("should send true to disableReturnButton when when last search is null ", function () {
        lastSearch = null;
        spyOn(ReturntoPage, 'disableReturnButton');

        ReturntoPage.clickReturnToPage();
        //console.log("lastSearch = " + lastSearch);
        expect(ReturntoPage.disableReturnButton).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant overwrite a variable that is declared in a function, so `lastSearch = "aa"` will have no effect in the function you wanna test. As `lastSearch` comes from the `sessionStorage`, you have to spy on this and return `"aa"` or `null`

```
it("should send true to disableReturnButton when when last search is null ", function () {
    if(typeof sessionStorage === 'undefined'){
      sessionStorage = {getItem: jasmine.createSpy().andReturn(null)}
    }else{
      spyOn(sessionStorage, 'getItem').andReturn(null);          
    }
    spyOn(ReturntoPage, 'disableReturnButton');

    ReturntoPage.clickReturnToPage();
    //console.log("lastSearch = " + lastSearch);
    expect(ReturntoPage.disableReturnButton).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

Comment: It worked! thanks for a clear explanation. I'm new to jasmine and junit and it's taking me a while to understand it!

Comment: It worked only within JSTD of eclipse. When I run it using maven I get an error saying that sessionStorage.getItem is not a function in http://localhost

Comment: Seems maven runs the test in a environment that not support localStorage. Updated my answer.

Comment: Mhmm, update my answer again. Did you know in which environment the test run?

Comment: windows 7 with firefox 10

Comment: Are your sure, assuming you are using the `jasmine-maven-plugin` it could either html-unit(which not support `session-storage`, http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1413/) or phantomJS.

Comment: I found this, and it works. It looks a little complicated to me thought:

Comment: var mockup = function() {

      var table = {};
      return {
        getItem: function(key) {
          return table[key];
        },
        setItem: function(key, value) {
          table[key] = value.toString();
        },
        clear: function() {
          table = {};
        }
      };
    }();
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: mockup });

    window.sessionStorage.setItem('lastSearch', 'val');

    spyOn(window.sessionStorage, 'getItem').andReturn('val');

Comment: What I see in the pomx is:                          <groupId>com.googlecode.jstd-maven-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>jstd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${plugin.maven.jstd.version}</version>

Comment: Please open another question for the maven topic, as the initial question is answered.